# Why does retain on an id<NSCopying> give a warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, release, retain

If I do the following, the compiler does not complain:

```
id foo;
[foo retain];
```

However, if I do the following, the compiler does complain:

```
id<NSCopying> bar;
[bar retain];
```

Specifically, it says:

```
Instance method '-retain' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Why is this? I thought an `id` pointed to a generic Objective-C object, and that I could pass `retain` to any Objective-C object.

Note this is a warning, not an error, so I can still compile the code and it seems to work. I also notice I can do the following to suppress the warning:

```
[(id)bar retain];
```

But I would think `id<NSCopying>` is a subtype of `id`, so anything that can be done on an `id` can be done on an `id <NSCopying>`...

Comment: Either there's a small contextual/conceptual difference here and `id <NSCopying>` really means "object of any class that implements `NSCopying` but nothing else", or it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Use `id<NSObject,NSCopying> bar` to eliminate the problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to say like `NSCopying* bar;`?

Comment: @rmaddy But that doesn't answer the "why".

Comment: @H2CO3 No, you already did that. I saw no need to repeat what you said. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't necessarily send `retain` to *any* Objective-C object. `retain` is part of the NSObject protocol. It so happens that all of Cocoa conforms to NSObject, but it is still not really universal from the standpoint of the language (it is possible to define a class that does not conform to NSObject or inherit from the NSObject class; it just isn't very useful).

Declaring something as `id<NSCopying>` means "Only let me send messages in the NSCopying protocol" — and NSCopying does not include `retain`. In order to send messages from the NSObject protocol, you must declare the variable as either `id` (in which case no type-checking occurs), `id<NSObject>` (in which case you can only send messages in the NSObject protocol) or as an instance of a class that conforms to NSObject.

In the case where you are declaring something as `id<NSCopying>`, you usually want to send the object `copy` instead of `retain`, since that's the whole point of declaring it that way. If NSCopying is standing in here for a protocol of your own, you can make the protocol itself conform to NSObject by defining it like this:

```
@protocol YourProtocol <NSObject>
```

And if you really need to declare a variable that conforms to two protocols (this is pretty unusual, but can crop up now and then), you can just declare it with a comma-separated list of protocols, like `id<NSCopying,NSObject>`.

Comment: Oh interesting. The reason I used `id<NSCopying>` is because I saw that `NSMutableDictionary` takes that type for the key of `setObject:forKey:`. Is that the reason it takes that instead of `id` - so it sends the key `copy` instead of `retain`? Another question is, it seems that `copy` is a method of `NSObject` anyway, not `NSCopying`... it seems what I want is `id<NSCopying,NSObject>` which I will use now.

Comment: `NSObject<NSCopying>*` is often preferable, because many methods of class NSObject are not part of protocol NSObject.

Comment: @Claudiu: I think you're a little confused by the fact that there are two things called NSObject — a class and a protocol. The NSObject class conforms to the NSObject protocol. The `copy` method is *implemented* by the NSObject class. but it's declared in the NSCopying protocol. (This is similar to how your table view delegate methods are implemented by your own class, but they're part of the table view delegate protocol.)

Comment: @GregParker: I disagree. For example, in Cocoa you will sometimes run into objects of `NSProxy`, which are not instances of the `NSObject` class, but do implement the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: @Chuck: Are you sure? If I look at the [NSCopying Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) it says the sole method the protocol provides is `copyWithZone:`. Further it provides a link to the `copy` method in the [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy): "This is a convenience method for classes that adopt the NSCopying protocol.""